# Why setInterval creates a closure in the reactjs counter?

Tags: reactjs

Below is official example in [React document](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-faq.html#what-can-i-do-with-hooks-that-i-couldnt-with-classes). The official explanation is

> The problem is that inside the setInterval callback, the value of count does not change, because we’ve created a closure with the value of count set to 0 as it was when the effect callback ran.

Can you show me where is the closure? I don't understand why the closure making the counter only reaches 2. I know closure, useEffect(), ()=> {} will not create a closure, but I don't understand how those concepts play together in this example to make the counter bug.

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";

function Counter() {
  const [count, setCount] = useState(1);

  useEffect(() => {
    const id = setInterval( () => {
      console.log("interval callback triggered");
      setCount(count + 1); // This effect depends on the `count` state
    }, 1000);
    return () => clearInterval(id);
  }, []); //  Bug: `count` is not specified as a dependency

  return <h1>{count}</h1>;
}

export default Counter;
```

Comment: If you want to find a good explanation, I suggest you read a old article by Dan from React js core team
https://overreacted.io/a-complete-guide-to-useeffect/#each-render-has-its-own-everything
it will clearly explain why it will only pick the initial value of the count

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This assumption:

> ()=> {} will not create a closure

is wrong. Arrow functions do create closure.

```
() => {
      console.log("interval callback triggered");
      setCount(count + 1); // This effect depends on the `count` state
    }
```

You are passing to `setInterval` a function. That function will capture values from its lexical scope and once captured these values will not be updated from subsequent state updates.

Comment: So arrow function will create a closure, but not creating its scope. is this right? My previous statement "arrow function will not create closure" is wrong, right?

Comment: Every function will create closure. I think you are confusing it with the fact that arrow functions close over the `this` value of their declaration. That is what is special about them. That is irrelevant here though

Answer (score 1):

To try explaining it in an understandable way, hopefully not too lengthy:

This is because in the callback function of `setInterval()`, the variable `count` in `setCount(count + 1)` is a copy of this variable the callback function got when it was created.

This copy of `count` remained in the closure as its initial value of 1. Therefore `count + 1` is always `1 + 1` which explains a result of 2 the whole time.

(Similarly, if you give the `count` a different initial value, for example `const [count, setCount] = useState(100)`, the number render in the component should always be `101`.)

This is why React request the variable `count` to be in a dependents array so that  `useEffect` will be notified if the callback function changed the value of `count` and update it in it's own scope.

(Then when `useEffect` runs again, naturally it will start another interval, which will end up in duplicates. This is why `clearInterval()` is returned as a cleanup function so that `useEffect` will know to clear the previous one before running again.)

Regarding your question about array functions `() => {}`, they have everything that a function has such as scope, closure, lexical context. The only difference (unrelated to the question here) is they don't provide their own `this` binding, instead retain it from it's enclosing lexical context: [more on this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this)